# Sorting numpy complex array, asignment by value and by reference

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment

I have came across to an interesting problem that I think has to do something with assignment by value and by reference using numpy arrays. Say I want to sort numpy array using classic bubble sort. If I do not include in the function numpy.copy or copy.deepcopy of the swapped value (i.e. the temporary variable) the sorting doesnt work (difference between bubbleSortComplex, bubbleSortComplex2). I have noticed the problem when sorting complex arrays by their abs value, however later discovered that the problem is also with simple ndarrays as well.
Although I have kind of find the answer to my problem I dont understand why this happens. I know I can use built in function, like numpy.sort in this case but I found this problem being more complex and problematic just for simple assignment of complex value to a variable.

```
import numpy as num
import copy as cp

def main():
    nlist = [14,46,43,27,57,41,45,21,70]

    nlist2 = num.zeros((5,1),dtype=complex)
    nlist2[0] = num.complex(1,2); nlist2[1] = num.complex(3,4); nlist2[2] = num.complex(2,7)
    nlist2[3] = num.complex(3,9); nlist2[4] = num.complex(1,3)

    nlist3 = cp.deepcopy(nlist2)

    nlist4 = num.zeros((5,1))
    nlist4[0] = 14; nlist4[1] = 46; nlist4[2] = 43; nlist4[3] = 27; nlist4[4] = 57

    nlist5 = cp.deepcopy(nlist4)

    # print original arrays
    print(nlist); print(" ")    # prints [14, 46, 43, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
    print(nlist2); print(" ")   # prints [[1.+2.j] [3.+4.j] [2.+7.j] [3.+9.j] [1.+3.j]]
    print(nlist3); print(" ")   # prints [[[1.+2.j] [3.+4.j] [2.+7.j] [3.+9.j] [1.+3.j]]
    print(nlist4); print(" ")   # prints [[[14.] [46.] [43.] [27.] [57.]]
    print(nlist5); print(" ")   # prints [[[14.] [46.] [43.] [27.] [57.]]

    # Sorting arrays and printing results
    bubbleSort(nlist); print(nlist); print(" ")             # prints [70, 57, 46, 45, 43, 41, 27, 21, 14]

    bubbleSortComplex(nlist2); print(nlist2); print(" ")    # prints [[3.+9.j] [3.+9.j] [3.+9.j] [3.+9.j] [1.+3.j]]

    bubbleSortComplex2(nlist3); print(nlist3); print(" ")   # prints [[3.+9.j] [2.+7.j] [3.+4.j] [1.+3.j] [1.+2.j]]

    bubbleSort(nlist4); print(nlist4)                       # prints [[57.] [57.] [57.] [57.] [57.]]

    bubbleSortComplex2(nlist5); print(nlist5); print(" ")   # prints [[57.] [46.] [43.] [27.] [14.]]

def bubbleSort(nlist):
    for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if nlist[i+1]>nlist[i]:
                temp = nlist[i]
                nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]
                nlist[i+1] = temp

def bubbleSortComplex(nlist):
    for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if num.abs(nlist[i+1])>num.abs(nlist[i]):
                temp = nlist[i]
                nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]
                nlist[i+1] = temp

def bubbleSortComplex2(nlist):
    for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if num.abs(nlist[i+1])>num.abs(nlist[i]):
                temp = cp.deepcopy(nlist[i])
                nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]
                nlist[i+1] = temp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `bubbleSortComplex` is giving you the wrong result for a very simple, yet probably harder to spot, reason.

You don't need to perform `deepcopy`, on `nlist[i]` to make it work but you need to be careful about the input to the function.

This code `nlist2 = num.zeros((5,1))` creates a 2d array (a column vector). In this case `nlist[i]` is not actually a number, rather it is a mutable array holding a single value. You can call `type(nlist[i])` to see that the output is `numpy.ndarray`.

If you change the array initialization to `nlist2 = np.zeros(5 ,dtype=complex)`, the type of `nlist[i]` will be immutable `numpy.complex128` and your code will work just fine.

```
nlist2 = np.zeros(5 ,dtype=complex)
nlist2[0] = np.complex(1,2); nlist2[1] = np.complex(3,4); nlist2[2] = np.complex(2,7)
nlist2[3] = np.complex(3,9); nlist2[4] = np.complex(1,3)

def bubbleSortComplex(nlist):
    for passnum in range(len(nlist)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if np.abs(nlist[i+1])>np.abs(nlist[i]):
                temp = nlist[i]
                nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]
                nlist[i+1] = temp
                
bubbleSortComplex(nlist2)
print(nlist2)
```

will print `[3.+9.j 2.+7.j 3.+4.j 1.+3.j 1.+2.j]`.

Whether you are using complex numbers or integers, the problem is not with these types. It is just that you are sorting an array of arrays (so, even if you change complex numbers for integers, you will observe the same effect).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Although I am quite new working in python (worked mostly in Matlab) and I tought that I undersnad the idea of pointers from my little experience with C and OOP, I kind of couldnt come up with a reasonable explanation why it doesnt worked as intended. My other furthed explanation after this post was, that I tought maybe `numy.ndarrays` are always considered as _mutable_ and thus I should reconsider possible flaws in all my codes. Anyway thank you for your response.